# How to search with only raw query JSON with Elastic Java API 6.5.1?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

How can I take the raw JSON String and query via the Java API? It should
work for any complex query that Curl accepts in Elastic.

For example:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "name": "<name>"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "address": {
              "query": "<address>",
              "fuzziness": 1,
              "prefix_length": 1,
              "operator": "or",
              "minimum_should_match": "80%"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "city_nm": "<city_nm>"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "state_province_cd": "<state_province_cd>"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I tried `Query Builders' simpleQueryStringQuery` method to achieve this but it creates the query which doesn't give a correct result.

For Example, to search a record using just name, this is the query which `simpleQueryStringQuery` is generating but instead of returning just one record it returns multiple records.

```
{
  "query": {
    "simple_query_string": {
      "query": """{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"match_phrase":{"name":"Neeraj"}}]}}}"""
    }
  }
}
```

whereas if I run the same query like this in my Kibana console that returns the correct number of results.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "name": "Jaas"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to use raw query? You can created any complex query using the Query builders provide by high level rest client.

Comment: Raw query gives us the advantage to modify it on the fly without changing my logic to build the query.